# Managing order of nested view defined in template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

**Question:**

How can I get list of nested views (as they are defined in template) and reorder them? Or move view from one parentView to another?

For example, I'd like to switch places column with date and column with image, or hide any of them on user action

```
{{#data-grid}}
  {{#grid-column}}
    {{format-date date}}
  {{/grid-column}}
  {{#grid-column}}
    {{#link-to 'somewhere'}}<img scr="i.png" title="hello"/>{{/link-to}}
  {{/grid-column}}
{{/data-grid}}
```

**Reason:**

I'm implementing datagrid with reordering and hiding collumns in runtime. Declaring view classes for all cases and then using them in controller seems ugly to me.

Already tried to use ContainerView but could not find the way to fill `childViews` with template contents

**UPDATE**
Source code of data grid in current state: http://pastebin.com/E61e6WCt

Comment: Implement data grids will give you some work. Have you looked the [ember-table](http://addepar.github.io/#/ember-table/overview)?

Comment: @MárcioRodriguesCorreaJúnior I did. Ember-table is good, but it is set up in controller and needs specific views for every case. It does not meet my specific requirements and modification seems to be very difficult. Besides I already made data-grid stub with server paging and sorting, and just want to add functionality.

Comment: Can you show some code of your current implementation. So we have something to work if.

Comment: @MárcioRodriguesCorreaJúnior updated post with pastebin link

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement this yourself, you should have a look at the [CollectionView](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CollectionView.html). Each of your columns should be one item in the content array of your view. Reordering the array should also reorder the DOM elements correctly.

**Here is a rough sketch:** Basically you are overriding `createChildView` within your subclass. You could pass strings into the content array indicating their type. Within `createChildView` you then can access the current item via the attrs object and its content property.

```
App.ColumnsCollectionView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
    content : ["date", "image"],
    createChildView: function(viewClass, attrs) {
        var itemFromContent = attrs.content; // is either 'date' or 'image'
        if (itemFromContent == 'date') {
          viewClass = App.YourDateColumnView;
        } else {
          viewClass = App.YourImageColumnView;
        }
        return this._super(viewClass, attrs);
    }
});
```

Comment: That seems to be the answer, if I could fill column array with views  defined in template, as in my example. Can you give me a hint on that?

Comment: @mavelin In your variant you can't use that nice declarative syntax of column definitions.

Comment: Yeah sure. I don't think that this possible out of the box with ember. But you absolutely have to start with the CollectionView and maybe you can eventually crate a nice syntax with the help of a helper.

Comment: I considered such solution, but i think it is not actually the best one. I still have to define `YourDateColumnView` and `YourImageColumnView` - that might be clumsy when you have lots of column types used only once.

Comment: @mavilein In this case your solution looks pretty similar to `ember-table` that was proposed by @MárcioRodriguesCorreaJúnior

Comment: Yeah sure. I just showed how you would approach it, if you want to do it yourself. One should compare the approaches and choose the best fit.

Comment: @Yuri: True, you can try to improve the solution with helpers, but you will have to do that yourself. This is no question for stackoverflow, as this is quite difficult, i guess.